# Sent email notification if a change happens on specified columns on a google sheet

Tags: javascript, excel, google-sheets

I have a Spreadsheet in Google Drive, which has two sheet in it "Production" and "Germination"

For the Production sheet, I to an email notification if a change has been made to the columns from A - F. Also if there is a row added or delete from the sheet.

The following code does the trick to some extent:

```
    function onEdit( e ){
    //To get email notification if any changes to the perticular cells
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("production");
    var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
    var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
    var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
    var recipients = "zeeshanrang@gmail.com";
    var message = '';
    if(cell.indexOf('C')!=-1){ 
      message = sheet.getRange('D'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
    }
    var subject = 'Update to '+sheet.getName();
    var body = sheet.getName() + ' has been updated. Visit ' + ss.getUrl() + ' to view the changes on row: «' + row + '». New comment: «' + cellvalue + '». For message: «' + message + '»';
    Logger.log(body);
   //MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
 };
```

But it sends me a mail on every edit, which is not required. It's required to send mail once every hour (if there is a change). Also right now it is only checking for changes on only Column C and not the rest of them.

Also, I was unable to understand `if(cell.indexOf('C')!=-1)` . Can someone explain me what does this statement means.

TIA

Comment: I use Zapier for that.

Comment: It (IndexOf) returns negative when nothing is found. In your case, if Range A1 contains C then this will execute... message = sheet.getrange..

Answer (score 0):

It means the following:

```
if(cell.indexOf('C')!=-1) // means that if you edit column C
       .......  //the following will happen
    }
```

**So to explain in more detail:**

`cell.indexOf('C')`-> search for 'C'

`!=` -> Does not equal

`-1` -> not there/ not found

`if(cell.indexOf('C')!=-1)` -> if indexOf('C') does not equal '-1' (i.e. if 'C' is there, do the 'if' statement

Comment: So that means cell.indexOf('C') has nothing to do with the Column C of the sheet.. ?